# Get bat file to contiune when lauching PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a bat file that is launching a powerShell script.  I would like for the bat file to keep moving after it launches the script and not wait for the powerShell script to complete.  Every time right now when i launch the powerShell script the bat files waits till the powerShell script finishes before it moves on.  Here is how I'm calling my powerShell script:

```
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "&'C:\Users\sharph\Desktop\test.ps1'"
```

Comment: Why do you need a batch file at all? Just run your script directly in PowerShell.

Answer (score 3):

[SS64 'start' help page](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

You'll want to start it with the start command, like this;

```
start "" "PowerShell"
```

This will start a program without waiting for it to close, although that behavior can be re-added with the `/w` or `/wait` option. The blank `""` is in place of the title, not always needed but generally a safe thing to add.

---

Perhaps this will work?

```
start "" "PowerShell" -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "^& 'C:\Users\sharph\Desktop\test.ps1'"
```

of course, the `&` had to be delimited to `^&`.